# Transfering cookies from a Request session to a selenium session

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am trying to take the cookies I have generated in a requests session to then open a web browser with selenium with those cookies. I have found that there are lots of people who have done this the other way round, so from selenium to requests but not this way.

I have tried to find the format and function in which I can convert the session.cookies function of requests to the selenium function to set cookies but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but you can get all the cookies with selenium (python) with:

```
driver.get_cookies()
```

This will get all the cookies on list of dict with the following format:

> {'domain': 'domain',
>   'name': 'name',
>       'value': 'value',
>       'path': '',
>       'expires': None }

So if you want to insert the cookies you have to do the following:

```
driver.add_cookie({
            'domain': 'domain',
            'name': 'name',
            'value': 'value',
            'path': '/',
            'expires': None
        })
```

You can go through the list to insert all the cookies with a loop.

Don forget that when you insert a cookie on selenium if the page was loaded before you must refresh the page

```
driver.refresh()
```